# Wi-Fi enable is not working

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo T410, but the Enable Wi-Fi is grayed out? I cannot connect to the internet

Comment: Please give more details about your problem.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of information just guessing:

The hardware switch might be turned off; happens to my notebook sometimes...

Try enabling the hardware, then the software (if necessary)